QTableView with stylesheet - indicators overlap text in Qt6
Update: This issue is caused by a Qt bug. They solved it, for release in Qt 6.9.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-129290
Original Post: We had to port code to Qt6, and one of the things that broke was the QTableView.

In Qt 5,15 and earlier, applying a style sheet with custom checkbox indicators worked fine.
In Qt 6.5.3, the custom image indicators overlapped over the default checkboxes and item text.
In Qt 6.6.3 and 6.7.2, the custom image indicators show fine, the default indicators no longer show, but the indicators are still overlapping the text.


It is definitely an improvement - but I don't know how to fix the overlapping of text, hidden under the indicator. The only options that are easy are also bad:

adding lots of spaces (text wrapping would still be affected).
inserting the checkbox as a separate column (I tried, but the header is formatted using QHeaderView::section:horizontal:first, QHeaderView::section:horizontal:only-one which I had trouble figuring out for the subsequent columns).
I tried to compare Qt versions, but I don't understand where the changes come from.
Currently, to have functionality, I ifdeffed out the style sheet. But it is desired by "stakeholders", among other reasons for consistency between desktop (upgraded) and embedded (not upgraded and needing large custom boxes).

This is a super simple example showing the behavior, if somebody can help me until Qt fixes it completely. It behaves the same as the real program, the images cover the text.
main.cpp:
#include "mymodel.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableView tableView;
    MyModel myModel;
    tableView.setModel(&myModel);

    QString viewStyle = "QTableView::item { padding: 10px; }\n"
                        "QTableView::indicator { width: 30px; height: 30px; }\n"
                        "QTableView::indicator:unchecked { image: url(:/checkbox_unselected.png); }\n"
                        "QTableView::indicator:checked { image: url(:/checkbox_selected.png); } ";
    tableView.setStyleSheet(viewStyle);
    tableView.setColumnWidth(0, 100);
    tableView.setColumnWidth(1, 100);
    tableView.setColumnWidth(2, 100);
    tableView.setRowHeight(0, 100);
    tableView.setRowHeight(1, 100);

    tableView.show();
    return a.exec();
}

mymodel.h
#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    explicit MyModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
};

mymodel.cpp
#include "mymodel.h"

MyModel::MyModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)  { }

int MyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    return 2;
}

int MyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    return 3;
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return QString("Row%1, Column%2").arg(index.row() + 1).arg(index.column() +1);
    }
    else if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole) {
        return (index.column() == 0) ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked;
    }
    return QVariant();
}


Not completely sure, but possibly related to QTBUG-126388 and/or QTBUG-124573. Does using setStyle("fusion") on the app change anything? I suppose you're on a High DPI system, aren't you?

@musicamante No, has no effect. Yes, maybe, or no - I set my Windows VM resolution low and still same overlap.

Are you sure that no scaling (including font scaling) is in effect in the guest VM? This seems to be related to that aspect, considering the size of the image and the slight blur of the icons. In any case, between 6.<don't remember> and 6.7 there has been some changes in the Windows QStyle (6.7 has introduced a new QWindows11Style based on the previous QWindowsModern) that caused some known regressions that are being currently addressed. Maybe wait a few days for 6.7.3 and see if it changes anything. It seems odd that the issue persists even using the "fusion" style for the whole app, though.

@musicamante I think it is not a size problem - it appears as if the images are completely ignored. (Oh the blur ? from my multiple runs I did screenshots - then put in word to have an image of all 3... And the original text is actually preceded by a couple spaces. Run the sample code to see.)

It may be a size problem, in the sense that the style is not correctly considering the pixmap scaling. In any case, you should clarify if your issue is just about having custom pixmaps for the check states, or if you are also interested in a specific size. Right now you're using the default style (print out the objectName() of the QApplication::style()) and behavior, which uses QStyledItemDelegate. Using QItemDelegate as suggested in the current answers will add more limitations in displaying (and it doesn't support style sheets), and using QCommonStyle is not a valid choice.

It's also important to know if using style sheet is common in your program, as they may be inherited. In any case, the only proper way to solve this is by: 1. finding out the cause of the issue (I still believe it's a quite relevant bug, that should be reported and solved); 2. work around the problem appropriately, without altering too much the current code structure (which is valid), instead of changing the behavior of other aspects (such as using a different data role or a limited style/delegate). If you are using QSS only for the check indicator, then you can just use a QProxyDelegate.

@musicamante 1) I reported the issue to Qt - but so far my past reports have been marked important and not solved; 2) My code has other style sheets, the QItemDelegate shown seems to respect them. I wished to see how to use a subclass of QStyledItemDelegate or QProxyDelegate but I don't know how.

QItemDelegate does not use QSS at all, except for generic properties set for any of its parents (like colors). Almost any QSS selector used for ::item will just be ignored, because QItemDelegate uses very few QStyle functions. You can just do some research about QStyledItemDelegate and QProxyStyle (there's no such thing as QProxyDelegate), as there are dozens of related posts even here on SO. Considering the issue and what it affects, assuming your report was properly submitted, it's quite possible it will be checked soon: as said, many recent changes in QStyles are being addressed lately.

Note that QSS are powerful in their simplicity, but also have lots of weaknesses. Some aspects of their implementation have been neglected from time to time, and have always been considered secondary to default QStyle implementations. The switch to default High DPI support also increased inconsistencies in their behavior to some extent. As said, if you just want to show your own "image" for check boxes, the more appropriate way to do so is to use a delegate or a proxy style. That said, please post the link to your bug report.

@musicamante I posted it in the issue itself, at the bottom. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-129290

So it was a Qt bug as I thought. I'd suggest you to provide your own answer considering the above report (and related commits), especially in sight of the fact that using a QItemDelegate (which fundamentally ignores style sheets as your original post implies) is not the proper solution, but just a partially reliable work around.

@musicamante: since the bug will be solved in Qt 6.9, the answer/workaround will be technically obsolete but I think still interesting - and useful for those who may be stuck on a version.

Thalia, among several options, I liked this very simple one.
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QItemDelegate>
#include <QPainter>

class Delegate : public QItemDelegate
{
private:
    QPixmap checkedPix, uncheckedPix;

public:
    Delegate(QObject *parent = nullptr):QItemDelegate(parent){
        checkedPix=qApp->style()->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_DialogApplyButton);
        uncheckedPix=qApp->style()->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_DialogCancelButton);
    }    

    void drawCheck(QPainter *painter,
                   const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                   const QRect &rect,
                   Qt::CheckState state) const{

        painter->drawPixmap(rect, state==Qt::Unchecked ? uncheckedPix:checkedPix);
    }
    
    /* you can also use: */ 

    // void drawDecoration(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QRect &rect, const QPixmap &pixmap) const{
    //  cell pixmap
    // }

    // void drawDisplay(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QRect &rect, const QString &text) const{
    //  cell text
    // }

    // void drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const{
    //  cell background
    // }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableView tableView;
    QStandardItemModel myModel;
    tableView.setModel(&myModel);
    myModel.setRowCount(5);
    myModel.setColumnCount(1);
    tableView.setStyleSheet(" QTableView::indicator { width: 30px; height: 30px; }");

    tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, new Delegate);//setItemDelegate, setItemDelegateForRow

    for(int row=0; row<myModel.rowCount(); row++){
        auto item=new QStandardItem("item");
        item->setCheckable(true);
        item->setCheckState(row%2==0 ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
        myModel.setItem(row, 0, item);
    }    

    tableView.show();
    return a.exec();
}


Thank you, this is working on my real code too.

I suggest using Qt::DecorationRole to display the image, and do without setStyleSheet.
I slightly modified your example based on the example from the Qt model help:

#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStyle>

class MyModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
private:
    QPixmap checkedPix, uncheckedPix;
    const int f=22;
public:
    explicit MyModel(QObject *parent = nullptr):QStandardItemModel(parent){
        checkedPix=qApp->style()->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_DialogApplyButton).scaled(f,f, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        uncheckedPix=qApp->style()->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_DialogCancelButton).scaled(f,f, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override
    {
        if(!index.isValid())
            return {};
        // Qt::DecorationRole
        if(role==Qt::DecorationRole){
            if(item(index.row(), index.column())->checkState()==Qt::Checked)
                return QVariant(checkedPix);
            else
                return QVariant(uncheckedPix);
        }
        else if(role==Qt::DisplayRole){
            return QVariant(item(index.row(), index.column())->text());
        }
        /*
        If you remove this "else if", the checkbox will not be 
        shown in the table cell, and its state can only be 
        controlled programmatically.
        */
        else if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole) {
            return item(index.row(), index.column())->checkState();
        }
        return {};
    }


    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent=QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return 5;
    }


    int columnCount(const QModelIndex & parent=QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return 1;
    }


    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                                         int role) const override
    {
        if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
            return {};

        if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
            return QStringLiteral("Column %1").arg(section+1);
        else
            return QStringLiteral("%1").arg(section+1);
    }


    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        if (!index.isValid())
            return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
        return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) | (Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
    }


    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
    {
        if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole) {
            item(index.row(), index.column())->setText(value.toString());
            emit dataChanged(index, index, {role});
            return true;
        }
        else if(index.isValid() && role == Qt::CheckStateRole){
            Qt::CheckState st= (value.toInt()==0 ? Qt::Unchecked : Qt::Checked);

            item(index.row(), index.column())->setCheckState(st);
            emit dataChanged(index, index, {role});
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTableView tableView;
    MyModel myModel;
    tableView.setModel(&myModel);

    for(int row=0; row<myModel.rowCount(); row++){
        auto item=new QStandardItem("item");
        item->setCheckState(row%2==0 ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
        myModel.setItem(row, 0, item);
    }

    tableView.show();
    return a.exec();
}


This is very interesting - but I must have clickable custom checkboxes - as shown in the Qt 5.15 image. Removing the stylesheet (the current compromise) gives me checkboxes, but not custom - and unclickable checkboxes are not useful. Your code suggests that I could go via making the checkboxes a separate column - can I make the first header column empty, the second be special, and the rest be QStringLiteral("%1").arg(section+1) ?

The checkboxes in my example are clickable. Clicking changes the image in the table cell. (At least for me, on Qt 6.7) Does my example work differently on your version of Qt?

Keeping the checkboxes means having double checkboxes - they must be replaced not more images added to the text. So, if I do as you suggested - removing the  if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole), there are no checkboxes, only images inside text. But from your example I am trying to take the header styling.

Maybe the QCommonStyle is what I need ? I will look at it, I wish I can find some example.

Regarding your question about empty and special columns - the state of a checkbox is controlled by the checkState() method on the cell item, and has three states. I only use two of them - you can use the third checkbox state to indicate that the image in the cell is not required to be displayed. Either use Qt::UserRole instead of Qt::CheckStateRole, or a class field in the model. Although I would still recommend using a delegate.
